# How to see if an object is blocked in Vb.net Webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have a webbrowser in a form that I am trying to see, if the following two items being displayed or not

```
<div class="alert alert-danger bet" style="display: block;">You Lost</div>

<div class="alert alert-success bet" style="display: none;">You Won</div>
```

I have searched and I can not find a solution to this. I have found how to search for them and find them without them having an ID but i can not see the style. If possible i would like to put the style result in a textbox for now until i figure out how to deal with the outcome.

EDIT

Ok so here's where i am now

```
 Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("alert alert-danger bet") Then
           TextBox1.Text = curElement.GetAttribute("style")
        End If
    Next
```

This returns System._ComObject and it seems to be the only thing that i can get to return at all.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so finally I believe I have a solution.

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("alert alert-danger bet") Then
                       If curElement.Style = "display: block;" Then
                TextBox1.Text = "True"
            ElseIf curElement.Style = "display: none;" Then
                TextBox1.Text = "False"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    End If
Next
```

Now obviously this is only showing one of my items so I will still have to handle the other but at least this gives me a True or False statement.